# Launchpad and source versioning while targeting different series of Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, ppa, launchpad

I have a package that can be build for both groovy and xenial. Ubuntu groovy have `libpng-dev` that resolves to `libpng16`. Plus it has `libpng12`. Xenial has no `libpng-dev` or `libpng16`. It has only `libpng12-dev`. It's ok for me to build the app with libpng12 on xenial, but I wan't to use libpng16 on groovy.

Also xenial's  `debhelper` seems to not provide `debhelper-compat`.

Thus I need `Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (=9), libpng-dev(>=1.2.0)` for groovy and `Build-Depends: debhelper (>=9.0), libpng12-dev(>=1.2.0)` for xenial.

My package version is `app-1.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb`

Launchpad seems to not allow building same source twice in same PPA. You can copy binaries between series, but not rebuild the source. It seems launchpad ignores that "0-ubuntu1" part of version when make this decision. Also it doesn't allow to upload any version less then it already have. So even if I end up with some series-dependent `Build-Depends:` in `debian/control` file - I couldn't benefit from this as source will be build only once. And I don't want to increment app version twice just to backport to xenial.

Are there any elegant solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems I figured out how to set up the control file to get the deb build via `pbuilder-dist` for both trusty (14.04) and groovy (20.10) on groovy machine.

1. Create `debian/compat` file with `9` inside. (old way of declaring compatibility)
2. Remove `debhelper-compat (=9),` from `Build-Depends:`  (it's incompatible with old way of declaring compatibility)
3. Leave `debhelper (>=9.0)` in `Build-Depends:`

I have `${shlibs:Depends}` in `Depends:`